# How to draw this relationship : Multiple composition of same instance

Tags: uml

I have a nodes. Two nodes makes link. Multiple links make chain.
How can I draw this relationship in UML?

I thought Chain as a aggregation of links. But I have not come across any diagram stating such relation with “filled diamond with 1..* in it”.

Sorry I cannot upload the picture of mine. Since the “.violet.class” format is not supported by stackexchage.

Thanks

Edit : Node is similar to the any point in map.

Link : (source node , destination node).

Chain: vector[multiple-links]

So node will exists irrespective of the link. Whenever you create a chain a new links will be created and it lives only the life time of chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UML class diagram modeling what you stated.
[image]

Comment: I agree with this model, with a few comments, though: (1) The question says: "Multiple links make a chain", so maybe the multiplicity should be 2..* instead of 0..*; (2) the navigability indicators (arrowheads and crosses) are not relevant, so I would not draw them; (3) it would be good to mention the multiplicities on the diamonds sides, usually 0..1.

Comment: The  node will live with out a link.  May I replace the line between Node and Link with ‘ line with empty diamond’ ?  BTW  how did you draw such diagram? what tool are you using?

Comment: @Kid I'm using Visual Paradigm, I have used it for a few years and I am quite happy with it. There is a non-commercial community edition.
I've made the composition into an aggregation as requested.

Comment: Chain can be created using one Link as well. The multiplicity between Link and chain is 1..*.  +1 for introducing the aggregation with multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

A chain has a predecessor and a successor. Either might be 0.

[image]

You might add a constraint that in a chain the first must not have a predecessor and the last no successor and also that no circle is allowed (all depends on the context where you model this).

Comment: I am sorry I guess I dint explain the question well.

Comment: My comments did not saved well. Actually my link class has two node instances. Chain class has multiple instances of links like “vector of links”. This is now a real graph kind of structure. There is no cyclic references.

Comment: Rather than commenting here, try to make your question clear and use the edit below your question. Until you get the status, upload a picture to a public server and post the link.